# Windows permissions and Remote Registry

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm working on a legacy project that is basically 2 windows PCs on a local network.

PC 1 is running a C++ application that as part of it's start up calls

`RegConnectRegistry(l_oAddr, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, &l_hRemoteBaseKey);`

On PC2

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regconnectregistrya

All 3 pcs are using strictly local accounts with admin privileges locally. PC1 is able to make that call successfully to PC2.

I've got PC3 that I'm trying to set up as an Impostor PC1, basically running the same application, with the same static IP on that network. PC3 gets plugged in, PC1 is removed. When I run the code on PC3, I get a Permission denied error.

The PC2 registry permissions for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE do not allow anything other than local admins to edit it. allowing all users full control of that key and it's children, also does not work. I'm certain the PCs all talk to each other just fine and no firewall is running on PC2.

Any thoughts on what permissions I am missing?

Comment: PC1 should not be able to access PC2 as admin by default. You must have done something to configure PC2 so it trusts PC1 as an administrator. You'll have to add PC3 to that same trust.

Answer (score 0):

So, as it turns out, if both PCs have the same user name and password. even if those are local to each pc, this will work fine and PC3 Will have access to PC2s registry.